# Why is my page extending past my content?

Tags: html, css, layout, removing-whitespace

I'm creating my own webpage here:  http://tinyurl.com/7n8jxbt

The problem is that after the footer, there is quite a bit of whitespace.  I see this whitespace in everything except Mozilla Firefox.

I tried to use inspect element to determine what was taking up the space but it says that nothing is there.

Does anybody know why all this space is there?

Comment: What whitespace do you mean? A screenshot where you mark the whitespace would be helpful.

Comment: The whitespace is caused by the empty `#sideword` element. Is there something that you will be putting in there later?

Comment: try to validate your html & css files first (W3 validator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the side word element which is rotated and gives the height to the document.

You probably don't need the margin or the top settings

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in your CSS file (line 1)

```
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif width:100%
```

Possibly, by this small error, the browser reads the rest of the CSS file completely wrong. So, put the `width` on a new line and close the `font-family` line after `serif` with a semicolon `;`.

EDIT: My Head Hurts' comment seems to be correct.

Comment: Good call on the semicolon though.  I'll make sure I fix that as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `span` with `id="SideWord"`. Remove the style `margin-top:100%` from this element and the white space will be gone.